# How to conditionally skip instantiation of fixture in pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Problem:

I have a fixture that takes about 5 minutes to instantiate. This fixture relies on a fixture from another package that I cannot touch. The time of the fixture can be drastically sped up depending on the state of a different (must faster instantiating) fixture. For example, this is the psuedo code of what I am looking to do:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def everyday_fixture(slow_fixture, fast_fixture):
    if fast_fixture.is_usable():
        yield fast_fixture
    else:
        slow_fixture.instantiate()
        yield slow_fixture
```

Is this a feature of pytest? I have tried calling fixtures directly but this is also not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`request`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#request) fixture for that.

```
@pytest.fixture
def everyday_fixture(request, fast_fixture):
    if fast_fixture.is_usable():
        yield fast_fixture
    else:
        slow_fixture = request.getfixturevalue("slow_fixture")
        slow_fixture.instantiate()
        yield slow_fixture
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [“factory as fixture” pattern](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#factories-as-fixtures):

```
@pytest.fixture()
def fast_fixture():
    def _fast_fixture():
        return fast_fixture_data

    return _fast_fixture


@pytest.fixture()
def slow_fixture():
    def _slow_fixture():
        return slow_fixture_data

    return _slow_fixture


@pytest.fixture()
def everyday_fixture(slow_fixture, fast_fixture):
    if fast_fixture():
        yield fast_fixture()
    else:
        yield slow_fixture()
```

Comment: This is certainly the right answer if you have control over the fixture. Unfortunately I could not modify the fixture (owned by a different engineering unit) and used in tons of existing tests). Instead, I did something like:

```
def _slow_internals():
    return slow_data

@pytest.fixture()
def slow_fixture():
    return _slow_internals()

@pytest.fixture()
def fast_fixture():
    return fast_data

@pytest.fixture()
def everyday_fixture(fast_fixture):
    if fast_fixture:
        return fast_fixture
    return _slow_internals()
```

Comment: Ok, so, if this was a working solution, please answer your own question to document it.